# Display a page after user click on link no login required in yii2 application

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

You click on link which is shared by admin through email. after clicking on this link you should view this page and no login process required for this. how it can be done?

I created this functionality and user easily redirects to this page but after few seconds the application redirects and login page is displayed.

```
 public function behaviors() {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['deal'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['?'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'deal' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Try to add a parameter `only`. Like this `'only' => ['deal'],` in to `access` behavior after `class` definition. If you want to show this page only to not authenticated users.

Comment: Why do you limit the requests for `deal` action to only `POST` method with `VerbFilter`? If it's supposed to be accessed through link from mail the browser will send `GET` request.

Answer (score 1):

You can check authorization on action

```
public function actionDeal() {

    if (\Yii::$app->user->isGuest && !\Yii::$app->session->has('adminshared')) {
        return $this->redirect(['site/login']);
    }

    // To do
}
```

and you can share link to another action, when user enter to this action you should set variable on session

```
public function actionSharedFromAdmin() {

    // To Do

    \Yii::$app->session->set('adminshared', true);
    return $this->redirect(['yourcontroller/deal']);

}
```